# Multiple default sorts in Kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'd like to set 2 default initial sort criteria for a kendo grid. I know how to set one sort criterium like this:

```
sort: { field: "sampleField", dir: "asc" }
```

But I fail to come up with a syntax to set up 2 criteria. Can someone show me how to do this?
Regards, Manu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**kendo ui grid using html5 murtiple default sort**

Make sure you specify sort on the Datasource like this

```
 sort: [
            {field: "field_1", dir: "asc"},
            {field: "field_2", dir: "desc"}
        ]
```

Here is the live working demo

[murtiple default kendo sort](https://jsfiddle.net/falafelsoftware/25hcozvs/)

For more details look into this  [RETRIEVE USER PHOTOS FROM ACTIVE DIRECTORY?](http://www.decatechlabs.com/what-is-ldap)